# What does #markup mean?

Tags: theming, 9

I meet this array key all the time in Drupal (for example in Symphony's `dpm()`) yet I am not able to find any documentation about it, what it does, how can I use it? How do I display something that is given as `#markup` value in Twig?

Comment: Take a look a the documentation for render arrays: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/9.3.x

Answer (score 4):

By using `#markup` in render arrays you can output raw HTML (passed through XSS filter to ensure security).

Here's an advanced example, with optional `#allowed_tags` and `placeholders`.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_foobar(&$variables) {
  $variables['video'] = [
    '#markup' => '<span>@video_label:</span> <video><source src="v.webm" type="video/webm"></video>',
    '#allowed_tags' => [
      'video',
      'source',
    ],
    '#attached' => [
      'placeholders' => [
        '@video_label' => t('Sample label'),
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

In Twig you just do:

```twig
{{ video }}
```

And in your browser you get the HTML with replaced placeholder and stripped `<span>`:

```html
Translated label: <video><source src="v.webm" type="video/webm"></video>
```

Comment: I would use a longer name instead of `@label`, this is a global placeholder replacing everything on the page it can find. Or use FormattableMarkup: `'#markup' => new FormattableMarkup('<span>@label</span>', ['@label' => $label])`

Comment: You are right here, I just wanted to show how attached placeholders work here. I've changed the name of the label to more specific one.

Answer (score 1):

Just by using the regular print twig syntax: {{ variable }}

The #markup is the html that will be on the final page sent from the server.

You can use a preprocess function to intercept and change the #markup if you need to.